# Twitter Oauth Api - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to access "screen_name" data sent by oauth api. I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

My current php code is this;

foreach($multi_responses as $response){

echo $response->user->screen_name;

}

This is the data sent by oauth: 
http://pastebin.com/SJbmYggQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you have got an array as a response, which is contains JSON strings. Try to parse JSON strings into an array or an object. If your $multi_responses variable in the foreach is fully contains the content of your linked file.

***Array version:***

```
<?php

    foreach($multi_responses as $response){

        $jsonDecodeArray = json_decode($response, true);

        if( isset($jsonDecodeArray['user']['screen_name']) ){
            echo $jsonDecodeArray['user']['screen_name'];   
        }

    }
?>
```

***Object version:***

```
<?php

    foreach($multi_responses as $response){

        $jsonDecodeOBJ = json_decode($response);

        if( isset($jsonDecodeOBJ->user->screen_name) ){
            echo $jsonDecodeOBJ->user->screen_name;   
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, json_decode was the one I forget about. Worked like a charm. Thanks buddy.